# How to format a USB storage not detected in Ubuntu?

Tags: usb-drive, removable-storage, file-format

I have a memory stick that is not mounted in Ubuntu and it doesn't works in Windows.

I can check is connected using

```
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 05e3:0727 Genesys Logic, Inc. microSD Reader/Writer
```

But I cannot mount it. I want to try formatting it to check if is detected again in Windows and Linux.

How could I do without mount it?

Comment: That most probably means it is utterly broken. Toss it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many ways to format a USB

### Command line

Type this command in the terminal which will help you identify the USB name i.e: sdb,sdc,etc...

> sudo fdisk -l

Make sure the USB is not mounted, if yes then you need to unmount it:

> umount /dev/sdX

Replace `sdX` with your device name

**Delete any existing partitions (from the SD card only).**

Enter the following on the command line (replacing x with the letter identified in step

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdx
```

- list the existing partitions by typing `p`.
- delete them by issuing the `d` command (repeat as needed until all partitions have been removed).

**Create a new partition.**

- Type `n` to create a new partition.

  - Type `p` to create a primary partition.
  - Type `8192` to select the sector. (See note)
  - Press `enter` to select the default last sector.
  - Type `t` to change the type of the partition.
  - Type `b` to select the FAT32 type.
  - Type `w` to save (write the changes to disk).

**Format the new partition**

Now to format the USB using FAT32,

> mkfs.vfat16 /dev/sdX

To format it using FAT16

> mkfs.vfat32 /dev/sdX

*After this reboot and check if you can see your USB in windows.*

---

### [Disk Uility](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-disk-utility/)

**To install Disk Utility if it is not installed:**

> sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility

After opening the app, click on the rectangle icon to unmount the USB

[image]

**Then as in the picture click on "Format"**

[image]

---

### [Gparted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/)

**NOTE:** *This method doesn't work for you since you have a problem with detecting your USB, but I have included it for others in the future*

**To install Gparted if it is not installed:**

> sudo apt-get install gparted

An advantage when using `Gparted` is that you can identify the USB name easily, as you can see from the picture below. My USB is mounted with the name `sdb`

[image]

**Then you can click on "Format To"**

[image]